# How to set an axis label (plotted with matplotlib) to come from the first list in a numpy array?

Tags: python, csv, matplotlib, 3d

I made a code which draws my data in a 3D plot with matplotlib. How can I do so that the label for one of the axis come from the first line in my CSV file. If I am not wrong the CSV is being passed as a numpy array in my code:

```py
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D  # noqa: F401 unused import
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy
import csv
from numpy import genfromtxt

data = genfromtxt('Removed_nodes_depths_A1_v3.csv', delimiter=',')
fig, (ax, bx) = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2, num=0, figsize=(20, 8),
                             subplot_kw={'projection': '3d'})
for i in range(1,data.shape[1]):
    ax.plot3D(numpy.repeat(i, data.shape[0]), numpy.arange(data.shape[0]),
              data[:, i])
gridY, gridX = numpy.mgrid[1:data.shape[0]:data.shape[0] * 1j,
                           1:data.shape[1]:data.shape[1] * 1j]
pSurf = bx.plot_surface(gridX, gridY, data, cmap='hsv')
fig.colorbar(pSurf)
ax.set_xlabel('Threshold')
ax.set_ylabel('Logic Depth')
ax.set_zlabel('# of Nodes Removed')
bx.set_xlabel('Threshold')
bx.set_ylabel('Logic Depth')
bx.set_zlabel('# of Nodes Removed')
plt.show()
```

The resulting image:[image]

**I would like the first line in my CSV: 1.00,0.999,0.9998,..., to be the header label in the X axis (Threshold) on the plotted images.**

The second image also doesn't look solid as it is supposed to. **Any suggestions on how to fix that?** Considering that there are a lot of data points (~5500x15).

My CSV looks like this:

```
1.0000  0.9999  0.9998  0.9997  0.9996
4144    6096    6859    7366    7876
1374    2119    2393    2615    2809
2122    3115    3466    3740    4011
1452    2322    2689    2877    3114
2677    3643    4047    4333    4652
1621    2224    2502    2704    2930
```

Comment: Consider using the first row directly as coordinates instead of using some index.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest how can I do that exactly?